# Why don't short-hand commands in mysql materialize

Tags: mysql

Let's take the following query:

```
SHOW FULL processlist
```

Which I believe is something along the lines of being a shorthand for:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST
```

However, why doesn't the first form allow any materialization when running queries, for example doing something like:

```
CREATE VIEWS x AS (show full processlist);
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM (show full processlist) x ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: Not really sure what answer do you expect beyond that mysql was designed this way?

Comment: @Shadow sure, are there any other ways around it? Or it's just something that is terminal and isn't composable in any way? Do you know if any other DBs support that kind of thing?

Comment: If you want to use the `full process list` in a query, use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST` as it actually behaves like a table. While `show full processlist` does share some underlying mechanics in the mysql with this table, its not at a SQL level and they aren't an alias or drop in syntax equivalent.

Comment: @David542 you really should decide what your question is about because you asked one thing in your question and then two different things in your subsequent comment! The workaround is using information_schema, but you are already aware of that. Utility statements and structures are pretty much product specific, so not really portable between database products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the SQL standard language specification that `CREATE VIEW ... AS ...` and `SELECT ... FROM (...)` only allow the dependent query to be a query-expression, i.e. a `SELECT` statement.

`SHOW PROCESSLIST` is not part of standard SQL, it's a MySQL-specific statement that implements a database administration function. There's no obligation for the sake of the SQL standard to make any `SHOW` commands conform to SQL semantics. So it's not necessarily supported for those any of the `SHOW` statements to work with other SQL clauses like `JOIN` or `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` (there are isolated cases like `SHOW TABLES WHERE...` but these are not supported consistently).